# vis.js change other item when in onAdd, onUpdate, onMove or onRemove

Tags: vis.js, redraw

I will change the content of an item (A) in the timeline when I change *another* item (B) with `onAdd`, `onUpdate`, `onMove` or `onRemove`. Because I need to call the callback function after changing item (B), I don't know, how I can change the content of item (A) and display it without new loading the entire timeline.

Is there a possibility?

Thanks

```
    onUpdate: function(item, callback) {
    entry = item;
    if (entry.editable) {

        // open dialog Window, #editOK is a button in this dialog window

        $("#editOK").unbind("click").click(function () {

            // allocation of data for saving in mysql

        .....
            dtf = moment($("#editFrom").jqxDateTimeInput('value')).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");
        .....

            saveDatas = $.param({ type: "U", .... });

            item.start = dtf;
            item.end = dtt;
            item.content = moment(dtf).format("HH:mm") + " - " + moment(dtt).format("HH:mm");
            item.codeDesc = des;
            item.pause = pau;
            item.idST = ist;

            editOrDel(saveDatas);
            // save of datas in mysql(actual item)

            // some things for other item

            saveDatas = $.param({ type: "A", ..... });

            editOrDel(saveDatas);
                        // save of other item(s)
            entry.id = aid;
            entry.group = group;
            entry.start = ....;

            times.push(entry);

            //  redraw the whole visjs schedule, I try it also without redraw and with the lines after the callback
            createCalendar("");

            // this callback was also after first editOrDel

            callback(item);

            timeline.setItems(null);
            timeline.setItems(times);
            timeline.redraw();
        });
    }
    else
        callback(null);
),
```

Comment: what gave you tried so far!?

Comment: Check all examples. Try to use redraw, setItems (set first to null and refill with the new items),  but it doesn't works inside.

Comment: Can't you please share a minimal simplified code of what you've tried?

Comment: New results from my investigation: 

in onUpdate, it's possible to make several different callbacks, which works properly. 

in onRemove and onMove, it isn't possible to make the same thing. The onAdd part I doesn't have try.